# How much time passed between Clone Wars S3E04, S1E22 and S3E10?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, chronology

According to [Star Wars: The Clone Wars Chronological Episode Order](http://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-the-clone-wars-chronological-episodeorder), S1E22 is one episode after S3E04 and S3E10 is one episode after S1E22. However we see some drastic changes in the appearances of Anakin and Ahsoka in S3E10 (Ahsoka is not present between S3E04 and S3E10 so I can't tell if she changed before one of that episodes in that period):

[image: S3E04]
S3E04

[image: S1E22]
S1E22

[image: S3E10]
S3E10 (Padme is wearing a hat)

Notice how Anakin's hair is significantly longer, Ahshoka's Montrals are longer and her shoulders are more muscular. Also Ahsoka seems to have grown closer to Anakin's height than before. Radical changes like that are not really seen between episodes prior, so has a more significant time lapse has occurred between them? What happened? How long was it?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on Wookieepedia about this. [*Sphere of Influence*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sphere_of_Influence) (S3E04) covered four concurrent events: [*Blockade of Pantora*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Blockade_of_Pantora), [*Kidnapping of the Papanoida Daughters*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kidnapping_of_the_Papanoida_daughters), [*Rescue on the Pantora Droid Control Ship*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rescue_on_the_Pantora_Droid_Control_Ship), and [*Rescue in the Mos Eisley Cantina*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rescue_in_Chalmun%27s_Cantina). Almost all of them mention [*Senate Hostage Crisis*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Senate_hostage_crisis) as the next event, and the pages of all of them link back. This event took place in [*Hostage Crisis*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hostage_Crisis) (S1E22).

On the *Senate Hostage Crisis* page, [*Showdown on Teth*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Showdown_on_Teth) is mentioned as the next event, and followed by [*Unidentified Jedi Ceremony*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_Jedi_ceremony). They both appear on [*Hunt for Ziro*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hunt_for_Ziro), the intermediate episode in the question. The ceremony event is followed by [*Bombing of Coruscant's Central Power Distribution Grid*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bombing_of_Coruscant's_central_power_distribution_grid) of [*Heroes on Both Sides*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Heroes_on_Both_Sides) (S3E10). So, it appears the time difference between S1E22 and S3E10 equal only with these two events. Considering the Clone Wars were busy times for the Jedi, I'd say we're talking about the time it takes for Anakin's hair to grow.

Outside of *The Clone Wars* show, there seem to be some events that refer to *Senate Hostage Crisis* as the previous event, according to Wookieepedia. First, there was [*Battle of Florrum*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Florrum), followed by [*Skirmish on Rodia*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skirmish_on_Rodia), and [*Mission to the Thicket*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mission_to_the_Thicket), which then wind up to *Showdown on Teth*. None of these events include Anakin but different Jedi Knights, so it's safe to say they don't prove the time any longer.

Comment: Can you add an estimate in time units?

Comment: @Worse_Username Twelve parsecs?